# Function Now when Windows is locked

Tags: excel, vba

I built an alert system which fires every 30 mins 24/7. It fires at the right time even when Windows is locked but I'm getting a hard time taking the date and hour.

I'm using `Date = Now` but instead of the real time it is showing this:
[image: Error]

On the screenshot, the pop up says `27/08/2138 13:30:00` when it should be `29/04/2019 13:00:00`

This only happens if the computer is locked.

```vb
Sub Actualizar_Online()
    
    Dim Inicio As Long, Fin As Long, Fecha As Date, Hora As Date

    AhorroMemoria True
    Declaraciones
    Hora = Now
    If Minute(Hora) > 30 Then
        Hora = TimeSerial(Hour(Hora), 0, 0)
    ElseIf Minute(Hora) < 30 Then
        Hora = TimeSerial(Hour(Hora) - 1, 30, 0)
    End If
    HoraInforme = Hora + Date
    Fecha = Date
    CargarDia
    With wsDB
        Inicio = .Cells.Find("SUR").Row
        Fin = .Cells.Find(Date - 1, After:=.Cells(Inicio, 1)).Row
        If Inicio <> Fin Then .Rows(Inicio & ":" & Fin - 1).Delete
        .Rows(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete
    End With
    wb.RefreshAll
    Segmentaciones
    
    wsAlerta.Cells(2, 1) = HoraInforme
    wsAlerta.Calculate
    ComprobarMail
    AhorroMemoria False

End Sub
```

Comment: `HoraInforme` is not declared: `Dim HoraInforme As Date` • I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)*.

Comment: It is declared on a global variable @Pᴇʜ that is not the problem :( I always use that option, which is on the top of the module.

Comment: Actually I cannot reproduce the issue. I build an [mcve] out of it (removed the not necessarey code) and it worked perfectly. • Are you sure that there is no variable named `Date`? This could break everything.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ my problem is that the code works flawless until the IT security policy jumps and locks the computer after 10 mins. Then the time variable just gets whatever... Not the real time, even though  I have workbook open event to fire this procedure every 30 mins and works fine.

Comment: Check your code to see if any function or sub multiplies `HoraInforme` by 2. (`Date * 2` incidentally is 27/08/2138)

Comment: If `HoraInforme` is a global variable then the issue is  that there is another function/sub that changes it!

Comment: @nacorid sorry but like I said the code works perfectly but something wrong goes on if the computer is locked. Like `Now` doesn't work properly. As for tim, I need at 14:00 to turn it into 13:30 and at 13:30 turn the time to 13:00. That's not the problem. The code works perfect until the lock.

Comment: Please post the value of `Now`,  `Hora` and `Date` when the code excecution is in this line `HoraInforme = Hora + Date`. Use a break point there. And the value of `HoraInforme` before and after this line is executed.

Comment: @Nacorid's comment should point you in the right direction. It appears `Date` is somehow multiplied by two. As a crude solution you could try dividing `Date` by two *in case* the PC is locked.

Comment: @TimStack That's not seriosly the solution you suggest! Please tell this was a joke.

Comment: Crude solution, to try. Nothing wrong with a bit of fiddling to find out what's wrong

Comment: I'm on a lunch break now, I'll post later the values for Hora and, Now and Date later. The thing that bothers me is the unusual behavior only when the computer is locked. But I'm 100% sure that the times are not being multiplied in amy case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may not be *the* bug, but it is *a* bug with similar output:

```
Hora = Now
If Minute(Hora) > 30 Then
    Hora = TimeSerial(Hour(Hora), 0, 0)
ElseIf Minute(Hora) < 30 Then
    Hora = TimeSerial(Hour(Hora) - 1, 30, 0)
End If
```

The `Now` function returns the `Date` + `Time`.  Your code will trim `Hora` to *just* time (rounded down to the nearest half-hour) if the minutes are >30 **or** < 30 - however, it will do nothing if the minutes are **exactly** 30.  Then, you are adding the Date on again

```
   Date    |  Time |       Now        |        Hora      |   HoraInforme 
29/04/2019 | 11:04 | 29/04/2019 11:04 |       11:00      | 29/04/2019 11:04
29/04/2019 | 12:47 | 29/04/2019 12:47 |       12:30      | 29/04/2019 12:30
29/04/2019 | 13:30 | 29/04/2019 13:30 | 29/04/2019 13:30 | 27/08/2138 13:30
```

Change your `If Minute(Hora) > 30` to `If Minute(Hora) >= 30`, and change `Hora = Now` to `Hora = Time`

Comment: Actually that **is** the bug.

Comment: Nice catch, I didn't see that.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ So, nothing to do with the Workstation being locked then?  **{facepalm}**

Comment: @Chronocidal This looks so clearly like **the** bug. It takes full `Now` (date + time) and adds the `Date` again. Which results in `Date * 2` that Nacorid found out already is exactly what the wrong `HoraInforme` value is. • Nice catch! • The lock was just something that happened randomly at the same time. I think it has nothing to do with the date issue.

Comment: This sounds like it... I will try it later!

Comment: @Chronocidal perfect! These little mistakes... :D